# Docker compose add local ip adress per network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to add local ip address per network, and that all port exposions be only on that local ip address, not on host ip adress.

Then we can map domain to ip address with ha proxy and forward all requests to any port to local ip address, and host would listen only on port 80.

Comment: No, because all docker networks need to "bridge" to one network card. that's why you get HOST-IP:PORT schema. If your host has many network cards, you could then attach networks to each of the cards and that will give you different IPs. Since you already going to do ha proxy, why would it matter to have different IPs per network?

Comment: I think you didn't understood me. I want different IP's per network. I want for example to have domain - test.app, and with ha proxy i would proxy every port to local adress 192.168.0.11 for example. Then everything i would create in that network, for example node container on port 3333, would work from test.app:3333 automaticly. But on host IP adress hostname:3333 would not be reachable. Do you understand me now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **docker network** to create a subnet:

`docker network create --gateway 172.16.1.1 --subnet 172.16.1.0/24 example_subnet`

Then just run a container with specific ip address:

`docker run --net example_subnet --ip 172.16.1.10 ...`